# Form_for issue finding the current route to pass into an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes

I have a form:

```
<%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>
```

That's located in my groups#show page. What I want to do is build an association with the current user, message id and current group. I have nailed the first two just fine with the following code in my MessagesController but I know I'm trying to find my @group_id after the params have been changed:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(:message => params[:message],
  :source => "web")

  respond_to do |format|
    if @message.save
      current_user.envelopes.create!(:user_id => current_user.id, :group_id => @group_id, :message_id => @message.id)
      format.html { redirect_to(group_path(@group_id), :notice => 'Message was sent.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
    end
  end
end
```

What I want to know is where should I catch the @group_id so that when they send a message the envelopes association is created and the user is redirected back to the group page they were just one (with the new message there now).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i've understood your problem correctly, you could stick the Group Id into the form as a hidden field:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group %>
```

Comment: That really set me on the right track. `<%= f.hidden_field :group_id, :value => @group.id %>` worked a charm!

Comment: I think it's best practice just to use @group i.e the whole object. This will still essentially set the id to what you need it to be.

Comment: I tried that but it kept throwing an error no matter the changes I made on the controller end. I think it had something to do with it confusing the User and Group that were being saved.